# ¿Cómo puedo cifrar/proteger/encriptar el código fuente html y javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera encriptar mi código javascript, que al momento de que alguien quiera ver código fuente se vea encriptado, el pequeño inconveniente es que es código PHP:

```
<?php $id_categoria = mvcontrolador::listadoTablaControlador("ultimaCategoria", null);
    if ($id_categoria == null or $id_categoria == '') {
        echo "var arrayUltimaCategoria=[{'0':'0',id_categoria:'0'}]);";
    } else {
        echo "var arrayUltimaCategoria=[".json_encode($id_categoria)."];";
    }
    if ($resultadoCategoria == null or $resultadoCategoria == '') {
        echo "var arrayValoresCategoria=arrayUltimaCategoria;";
    } else {
        echo "var arrayValoresCategoria=[".json_encode($resultadoCategoria)."];";?>
    <?php }?>
```

Y se ve así al ver código fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: El código javascript puedes ofuscarlo, aquí te coloco una herramienta con la que puedes conseguirlo: https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Comment: La respuesta de Pedro funciona pero el problema de un ofuscador es que pierdes algo de rendimiento, lo mejor sería usa un minificador.

Comment: Php dentro de un script, wow....

Answer (score -1):

Ya encontré la solución amigos, lo hice fue cifrar el nombre de la variable para que no sea visto a simple vista, ademas de también cifrar el contenido de array con base64_encode() de php, es seguridad de bajo nivel, pero al menos el contenido del array no sale a simple vista.

`<?php $id_categoria = mvcontrolador::listadoTablaControlador("ultimaCategoria", null);
    if ($id_categoria == null or $id_categoria == '') {
    echo "var dmFyIGFycmF5VWx0aW1hQ2F0ZWdvcmlh=[{'0':'0',id_categoria:'0'}]);";
    } else {
    echo "var dmFyIGFycmF5VWx0aW1hQ2F0ZWdvcmlh=[".json_encode(base64_encode(json_encode($id_categoria)))."];";
    }
    if ($resultadoCategoria == null or $resultadoCategoria == '') {
    echo "var YXJyYXlWYWxvcmVzQ2F0ZWdvcmlh=dmFyIGFycmF5VWx0aW1hQ2F0ZWdvcmlh;";
    } else {
    echo "var YXJyYXlWYWxvcmVzQ2F0ZWdvcmlh=[".json_encode(base64_encode(json_encode($resultadoCategoria)))."];";}?>`

Luego en un archivo .js aparte paso los valores "encriptados" y los desencripto con un metodo llamado atob() y un JSON.parse() para pasarlo de string a objeto:

`arrayUltimaCategoria=JSON.parse(atob(dmFyIGFycmF5VWx0aW1hQ2F0ZWdvcmlh));
arrayValoresCategoria=JSON.parse(atob(YXJyYXlWYWxvcmVzQ2F0ZWdvcmlh));`

Después encripto u ofusco el archivo .js aparte, por ahora cuando vayan a ver código fuente dentro del  se encontraran con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sé, soy nuevo, pero base64 cualquiera puede decodificar, hasta lo que sé no sé necesita ningún método de descifrado, solo de decodificación, entonces para esforzarse en pasar en base 64 si al final quien vea tu código va a poder acceder al contenido? Al menos el usuario estándar no lo vería, pero alguien con un poquito de experiencia en el tema y con malas intenciones podría acceder.

Comment: No te preocupes Carlos Daniel Zárate Ramírez, ahora uso weakmap, sube un poco la seguridad integrando como llave el objeto (clase) en sí.